# Is it possible to implement conditions in the offset of the lag() function on Snowflake?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a table on Snowflake that contains messages between company admins and users. Here's what the table looks like.

| id | message | destination | messageable_id | sent_at |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Hello Customer! | outgoing | 1700103 | 2022-03-22 22:42:11.000 |
| 2 | Hello Company! | incoming | 1700103 | 2022-03-22 22:39:56.000 |

I have been trying to get the response time by using `lag(sent_at,1) over (partition by messageable_id order by sent_at)` to get the sent_at value from the previous row, and calculating the datediff there as the response time.

However, I realized that there are records where I have 3 consecutive outgoing rows, and it would make more sense for me to get the earliest sent_at value in that group rather than the latest one.

I'm wondering if it would be possible to implement a condition on the offset in the lag() syntax. Something along the lines of IF 3 consecutive outgoing values in column, then offset = 3 else 1.

So far, I've looked into using window functions but no luck there.

Answer (score 0):

here is one way :

```
select *,lag(sent_at,1) over (partition by messageable_id order by sent_at) 
from (
   select * , row_number() over (partition by messageable_id , destination order by sent_at asc) rn
   from tablename
) t where rn = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

So there are a couple of points, first, you messages by ID the id's are traveling back in time, and you have no three message example data, and not expected best case outcomes results:

so lets make some data that makes more sense:

```
with data(id, message, destination, messageable_id, sent_at) as (
    select * from values
        (1, 'msg with 2', 'incoming', 1700103, '2022-03-22 22:39:56.000'::timestamp_ntz),
        (2, 'msg with 2', 'outgoing', 1700103, '2022-03-22 22:42:11.000'::timestamp_ntz),
    
        (3, 'msg with 3', 'incoming', 1700104, '2022-03-22 22:39:56.000'::timestamp_ntz),
        (4, 'msg with 3', 'outgoing', 1700104, '2022-03-22 22:42:11.000'::timestamp_ntz),
        (5, 'msg with 3', 'outgoing', 1700104, '2022-03-22 22:43:11.000'::timestamp_ntz)
)
```

now using your "what I tried SQL"

```
select 
    *
    ,lag(sent_at,1) over (partition by messageable_id order by sent_at) as val_sent_at
from data
order by messageable_id, sent_at;
```

| ID | MESSAGE | DESTINATION | MESSAGEABLE_ID | SENT_AT | VAL_SENT_AT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | msg with 2 | incoming | 1700103 | 2022-03-22 22:39:56.000 | null |
| 2 | msg with 2 | outgoing | 1700103 | 2022-03-22 22:42:11.000 | 2022-03-22 22:39:56.000 |
| 3 | msg with 3 | incoming | 1700104 | 2022-03-22 22:39:56.000 | null |
| 4 | msg with 3 | outgoing | 1700104 | 2022-03-22 22:42:11.000 | 2022-03-22 22:39:56.000 |
| 5 | msg with 3 | outgoing | 1700104 | 2022-03-22 22:43:11.000 | 2022-03-22 22:42:11.000 |

and you are saying in `1700104` messages you want the first `sent_at` of the sequence, this can be achieved with [FIRST_VALUE](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/first_value.html), but the first row will also have a value:

```
select 
    *
    ,first_value(sent_at) over (partition by messageable_id order by sent_at) as first_sent_at
from data
order by messageable_id, sent_at;
```

| ID | MESSAGE | DESTINATION | MESSAGEABLE_ID | SENT_AT | FIRST_SENT_AT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | msg with 2 | incoming | 1700103 | 2022-03-22 22:39:56.000 | 2022-03-22 22:39:56.000 |
| 2 | msg with 2 | outgoing | 1700103 | 2022-03-22 22:42:11.000 | 2022-03-22 22:39:56.000 |
| 3 | msg with 3 | incoming | 1700104 | 2022-03-22 22:39:56.000 | 2022-03-22 22:39:56.000 |
| 4 | msg with 3 | outgoing | 1700104 | 2022-03-22 22:42:11.000 | 2022-03-22 22:39:56.000 |
| 5 | msg with 3 | outgoing | 1700104 | 2022-03-22 22:43:11.000 | 2022-03-22 22:39:56.000 |

So if that first row not being a null is a problem we can solved with [NULLIF](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/nullif.html)

```
select 
    *
    ,first_value(sent_at) over (partition by messageable_id order by sent_at) as first_sent_at
    ,nullif(first_sent_at, sent_at) as nullif_result
from data
order by messageable_id, sent_at;
```

| ID | MESSAGE | DESTINATION | MESSAGEABLE_ID | SENT_AT | FIRST_SENT_AT | NULLIF_RESULT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | msg with 2 | incoming | 1700103 | 2022-03-22 22:39:56.000 | 2022-03-22 22:39:56.000 | null |
| 2 | msg with 2 | outgoing | 1700103 | 2022-03-22 22:42:11.000 | 2022-03-22 22:39:56.000 | 2022-03-22 22:39:56.000 |
| 3 | msg with 3 | incoming | 1700104 | 2022-03-22 22:39:56.000 | 2022-03-22 22:39:56.000 | null |
| 4 | msg with 3 | outgoing | 1700104 | 2022-03-22 22:42:11.000 | 2022-03-22 22:39:56.000 | 2022-03-22 22:39:56.000 |
| 5 | msg with 3 | outgoing | 1700104 | 2022-03-22 22:43:11.000 | 2022-03-22 22:39:56.000 | 2022-03-22 22:39:56.000 |

but if you have multiple messages, it would null all of them. Another option is to use [ROW_NUMBER](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/row_number.html), and to make values stable would be to use id to help order values.